# Populating Select with Jquery .ajax using json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

Have tried hard but no results
my Json looks like which i have created with php like this (header also sent before data)

```
{"users":[
{"id":"3256","name":"Azad Kashmir"},
{"id":"3257","name":"Balochistan"},
{"id":"3258","name":"Federally Administered Tribal Areas"},
{"id":"3259","name":"Islamabad"},
{"id":"3260","name":"North-West Frontier"},
{"id":"3261","name":"Northern Areas"},
{"id":"3262","name":"Punjab"},
{"id":"3263","name":"Sindh"}], 
"results":8}
```

and my client side code like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#country").change(function(){
var vc = $("#country").val();
    $.ajax({url: "../inc/region_json.php", type: "get", data:{country:vc}, dataType: 'json', success: function(json){
        $("#divx").html(json);
         $.each(json, function(i, value) {
        $('#region').append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', value));
    }});
});

});
</script>
```

I want to populate

```
region: <select name="region" id="region">
<option value="0">Choose a Country First</option>
</select><BR /><BR />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#country").change(function(){
    var vc = $("#country").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "../inc/region_json.php", type: "get", data: { country: vc }, dataType: 'json', success: function (json) {
            $("#divx").html(json);
            $.each(json.users, function (i, value) {
                $('#region').append('<option value="'+value.id+'">' + value.name + '</option>');
            });
        }
    });
   });

});
```

Here is sample demo as well:- [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fZTgH/43/)

Comment: Gr8 code is working now... Plus i had to add 
$("#region").html('');